# Tomcat Connectors (mod_jk) make error

Tags: macos, apache, tomcat, makefile, mod-jk

I'm trying to install Tomcat Connectors (mod_jk) on my Mac and I'm following the instructions from the following sites.

http://pablotips.blogspot.com/2015/01/compiling-modjk-on-mac-os-x-1010.html

https://www.bartbusschots.ie/s/2009/05/05/installing-mod_jk-for-apache-22-on-mac-os-x-105-leopard/

I get the following error when I run the make process.

[image]

Q.1 How can I fix this error and compile the make process?

Q.2 Will this help me serve my files from the default apache /Sites directory using Tomcat server?

Answer (score 1):

1. find apr_lib.h

   `$ sudo find / -name "apr_lib.h"`
2. add lib

   LDFLAGS='-L[path]' CFLAGS='-I[path]'

   `$ ./configure CFLAGS='-arch x86_64' APXSLDFLAGS='-arch x86_64' LDFLAGS='-L/usr/include/apr-1' CFLAGS='-I/usr/include/apr-1' --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs`

Answer (score 0):

When you are starting Tomcat you are seeing following error as well:

> INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal
>     performance in production environments was not found on the
>   java.library.path

The APR is Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments.

Prerequisites for installing APR
    APR library
    APR-util library
    OpenSSL library

Download it from this link http://apr.apache.org/download.cgi and integrate to Tomcat. This will fix your problem

When you installed and integrated then when you restart Tomcat server. You will see like following:

> After restarting the Tomcat service, we can get the following message
>   in catalina.out log if APR was installed successfully.
>   ------------ Oct 07, 2015 8:08:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init INFO: Loaded APR
>   based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.29 using APR version 1.5.2. Oct
>   07, 2015 8:08:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
>   INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters
>   [false], random [true].

Let me know if you need more help from my end

Comment: Is this APR library available for Mac OS X env? I'm not sure if I understand the prerequisites for installing line. Are they seprate APR Library, APR-Util library and OpenSSL library?

Comment: Check this http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2011/01/add-apr-based-native-library-for-tomcat.html

Comment: google and you will find too many articles as to how you can install APR library on MAC

Comment: I've not had a chance to look at it, I will surely look at your resolution this week and get back to you.